# URL GET parameter representing and parsing embedded objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, get

I'm working on an API that consists of several collections that have relations to each other. I want to give users the opportunity to eagerly fetch records from associated collections via a GET url parameter.

For instances

```
/api/clients/
```

Would return an array of objects, each representing a client.

But clients have "employees" and "templates". "Templates" also have "revisions." And lastly, "revisions" have "groups"

My strategy for the format of the url parameter is something like this:

```
/api/clients?expand=[employees][templates[revisions[groups]]]
```

Which represents:

```
clients
 + employees
 + templates
   + revisions
     + groups
```

My question is, what is a good way to go about parsing a string in this format: `[employees][templates[revisions[groups]]]`
to arrive at an object like this:

```
{
  "employees": {},
  "templates": {
    "revisions": {
      "groups": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Or something similar that's easy to work with. I'm working in NodeJS so any answers specific to that environment are a plus. Regex?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using POST.

Comment: Did you tried pass the object , in `json` format? Or you tried but that is not good for you?

Comment: I could use post, but I was leaning towards trying to stay true to the intended purposes of GET/POST/PUT/DELETE HTTP verbs

Comment: @Kovge, representing this data in JSON format could be done - it's just a tad messy. If I could accept the data in the above format it would be less verbose than using JSON.

Comment: I guess I should be asking how to represent a tree in a string

Comment: Your string looks like a 'DOM tree (NOT XML)', if you want to use that format, you should write a small dom parser, regex-s does not work good on dom trees.

Answer (score 1):

Going off @Kovge 's suggestion, I'm going to handle this situation with a JSON string passed in my URL get request. It's a bit verbose, but should be acceptable.

Here's how I'd represent my eager-fetching associated collection records:

```
[
  {
    "resource": "employees"
  },
  {
    "resource": "templates",
    "extend": [
      {
        "resource": "revisions",
        "extend": [
          {
            "resource": "groups"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically using arrays of objects with "resource" parameters and optional "extend" parameters. My request will end up looking like this: (url encoded)

```
http://example.com/api/clients?extend=%5B%7B%22resource%22%3A%22employees%22%7D%2C%7B%22resource%22%3A%22templates%22%2C%22extend%22%3A%5B%7B%22resource%22%3A%22revisions%22%2C%22extend%22%3A%5B%7B%22resource%22%3A%22groups%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D
```

## EDIT:

This is what my result ended up looking like, still playing with things.
[image]

Comment: +1. This is the method I've always used for sending objects in GET requests.